# PHP JSON parsing, only showing one of three parameters

Tags: php, html, json, forms, post

I have a html page that sends a HTTP POST to a php page, and have embedded a JSON object as a parameter. When I try to retrieve the parameters, however, I can only retrieve "pass" and nothing else. Am I missing something about parsing JSON in php??

html POST form:

```
<form method="POST" action="......../username_exist.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="param" value='{"username":"user123","pass":"147852369qwerfdsazxcv","funny":"funny"}' />
<input type="submit" value="Click Me to submit" />
</form>
```

and the php page:

```
$param = json_decode($_POST['param']);
$username = $param['username'];
$pass = $param['pass'];
$funny = $param['funny'];
echo $pass;
echo $username;
echo $funny;
```

give the result of:

> 147852369qwerfdsazxcv

Comment: Can you display what echo's out of POST['param'] please? Specifically did it get urlencoded?

Comment: @xandar `echo "1".$_POST['param']."2";` gives `1{\"username\":\"user123\",\"pass\":\"147852369qwerfdsazxcv\",\"funny\":\"funny\"}2` . I think I see the problem now, but how do I get pass this? PHP is auto-escaping the " , how do I stop this?

Comment: but , I still do not see why would "pass" work, when "username" and "funny" failed

Comment: To get an associative array returned the second parameter in json_decode must be true. I put the line in an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've read from [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), calling `json_decode` **without** `assoc` param will return an object, so you need to access its property like `$param->pass`, `$param->username`.

Cheers!

Comment: Thankyou. It works now, but it now seems crazy that "pass" SOMEHOW managed to work...... hmmmmmmm nevermind

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on my local:

```
$param = json_decode($_POST['param']);
$username = $param->username;
$pass = $param->pass;
$funny = $param->funny;
echo $pass;
echo $username;
echo $funny;
```

The difference is that I used the `->`, since it is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Philip is right, you need to add true as a second parameter to json_decode to get an array back.

```
$param = json_decode( $_POST['param'], true );
```

..would return the json as an associative array and make the rest of your code work as expected.